# Collapse long text (with more/less links)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote a little function to compact long text. I am relatively new to JavaScript so I am not sure I wrote it as elegantly as possible. I wrote it to be runnable on the server side (Node.js) as well, so can't use jQuery or such. Can the code be improved?

```
// change a long text into  "bla bla bla... (more)" where (more) is a link to open the rest of the text
// compact text if over maxWords words (split by ' ', default 25)
//           or if over maxRows lines (split by '<br>', default 2)
// but avoid compacting if no more than "almostFinished" (default 5) words to the end of the text
compactText = function(text, prefix, maxWords, maxRows, almostFinished) {
    if (!maxWords) {
        maxWords = 25;
    }
    if (!maxRows) { 
        maxRows = 2;
    }
    if (!almostFinished) {
        almostFinished = 5;
    }

    var result = [];
    var compacted = false;
    // escape the html code in the text
    text = (text || '').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;').replace(/\r/g, ' ').replace(/\n/g, ' <br> ')
    var pn = text.split(' ');
    var row = 1;
    for (var word=0; word< pn.length; word++) {
        if (pn[word] === "<br>") {
            row++;
        }
        if (!compacted && (row > maxRows || word == maxWords) && word< pn.length - almostFinished) {
            compacted = true;
            /* too long - add a (more) link and open hidden span for rest of text */
            result.push('<span class="'+prefix+'-more-text">...<a href="#" onclick="javascript:$('+
                    "'."+prefix+"-more-text').toggle(); return false;"+
                    '">(show more)</a></span>');
            result.push('<span class="'+prefix+'-more-text" style="display:none">');
        }

        result.push(pn[word]);
    }
    if (compacted) {
        // compacted: add link to toggle back (less) and close the hidden span.
        result.push('<a href="#" onclick="javascript:$('+
            "'."+prefix+"-more-text').toggle(); return false;"+
            '">(show less)</a></span>');
    }

    return result.join(' ');
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the br? Can't you use `white-space: pre-line;`?

Comment: I didn't know about the white-space css, it certainly removes the need for replacing \n with <br>,  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instead of `pn` use a longer variable name. A variable like this with such a big scope really deserves a longer name. It would make the code easier to read.

   ```
   var pn = text.split(' ');
   ```
2. Instead of commenting use the comment name as a function name:

   ```
   // escape the html code in the text
   text = (text || '').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;').replace(/\r/g, ' ').replace(/\n/g, ' <br> ')
   ```

   I'd write this:

   ```
   function escapeHtml(text) {
       if (!text) {
           return "";
       }
       return text.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;').replace(/\r/g, ' ').replace(/\n/g, ' <br> ')        
   }
   ```
3. I'd create a `createToggleLink` function.

   ```
   function createToggleLink(prefix, linkText) {
       return '<a href="#" onclick="javascript:$(' +
               "'." + prefix + "-more-text').toggle(); return false;" +
               '">(" + linkText + ")</a>');
   }
   ```

   It removes some code duplication and furthermore makes it more explicit that you close the `span` tag:

   ```
   if (compacted) {
       var toggleLink = createToggleLink(prefix, '(show less)');
       result.push(toggleLink);
       result.push('</span>');
   }
   ```

   So, the comment is unnecessary, the code says the same.